# How to implement ipad-like password field behaviour in a text input field using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any plugin similar to the iPad-like password field behaviour. We need to show only the focus number that the customer enters when they enter their credit card number, and then switch to a bullet once the customer types the next number.

For numbers that have been entered prior to the number being entered, they all need to be changed to the bullet style.

Comment: CSS Tricks has [some suggestions](https://css-tricks.com/better-password-inputs-iphone-style/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Jquery plugin. tried this out. Hope this works for you - http://jsfiddle.net/Lhw7xcy6/12/

```js
(function () {
    var config = {},
    bulletsInProgress = false,
        bulletTimeout = null,
        defaultOpts = {
            className: 'input-long',
            maxLength: '16',
            type: 'tel',
            autoComplete: 'off'
        };
    var generateBullets = function (n) {
        var bullets = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            bullets += "\u25CF";
        }
        return bullets;
    },
    getCursorPosition = function (elem) {
        var el = $(elem).get(0);
        var pos = 0;
        var posEnd = 0;
        if ('selectionStart' in el) {
            pos = el.selectionStart;
            posEnd = el.selectionEnd;
        } else if ('selection' in document) {
            el.focus();
            var Sel = document.selection.createRange();
            var SelLength = document.selection.createRange().text.length;
            Sel.moveStart('character', -el.value.length);
            pos = Sel.text.length - SelLength;
            posEnd = Sel.text.length;
        }
        return [pos, posEnd];
    },
    keyInputHandler = function (e, elem, $inpField) {
        var keyCode = e.which || e.keyCode,
            timeOut = 0,
            $bulletField = $(elem),
            tempInp = $bulletField.data('tempInp'),
            numBullets = $bulletField.data('numBullets');
        var position = getCursorPosition(elem);
        if (keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) {
            e.preventDefault();
            clearTimeout(bulletTimeout);
            $bulletField.val(generateBullets(numBullets) + String.fromCharCode(keyCode));
            tempInp += String.fromCharCode(keyCode);
            numBullets += 1;
            bulletsInProgress = true;
            timeOut = 3000;
        } else if (keyCode == 8) {
            clearTimeout(bulletTimeout);
            tempInp = (position[0] == position[1]) ? tempInp.substring(0, position[0] - 1) + tempInp.substring(position[1]) : tempInp.substring(0, position[0]) + tempInp.substring(position[1]);
            numBullets = (position[0] == position[1]) ? numBullets - 1 : numBullets - (position[1] - position[0]);
            tempInp = ($.trim($bulletField.val()) === '') ? '' : tempInp;
            numBullets = ($.trim($bulletField.val()) === '') ? 0 : numBullets;
            timeOut = 0;
        } else {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
        $bulletField.data('numBullets', numBullets);
        $bulletField.data('tempInp', tempInp);
        $inpField.val(tempInp);
        $('#output').val(tempInp); // testing purpose
        bulletTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
            $bulletField.val(generateBullets(numBullets));
            bulletsInProgress = false;
        }, timeOut);
    };
    $.fn.bulletField = function (options) {
        var opts = $.extend({}, defaultOpts, options);
        //console.log(opts);
        this.each(function () {
            var $inpField = $(this),
                id = $inpField.attr('id');
            $inpField.after('<input id="bullet_' + id + '" type=' + opts.type + ' maxlength=' + opts.maxLength + '  autocomplete=' + opts.autoComplete + ' class=' + opts.className + '>');
            $inpField.hide();
            var bulletFieldId = 'bullet_' + id;
            var $bulletField = $('#' + bulletFieldId);
            $bulletField.data('numBullets', 0);
            $bulletField.data('tempInp', '');
            $('#' + bulletFieldId).on('keydown', function (e) {
                keyInputHandler(e, this, $inpField);
            });
            $('#' + bulletFieldId).on('blur', function () {
                //$inpField.trigger('blur');
            });
        });
        return this;
    };
}());
$(function () {
    /*USAGE  - invoke the plugin appropriately whenever needed. example -onclick,onfocus,mousedown etc.*/
    //$('body').on('mousedown', '#bulletField', function () {
        $('#bulletField').bulletField();
        //$('body').off('mousedown');
   // });
    /* ---OR ---- 
        $('#bulletField').bulletField({
   className: 'input-short',
   maxLength : '4'
   });*/
});
```